# Change taskbar location with powershell and autohide Windows 10 build 14393

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to place the taskbar location to the top with powershell and let it auto-hide.

I found this website with option three what works for most people. The only problem is I'm trying to get this fixed in Windows 10 build 14393.
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1066-taskbar-move-location-desktop-screen.html

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2]
```

I came across one forum who told that it was changing a registry value. I tried to do so but it didn't work. When I changed the location to the top, I looked in the regedit again and the same value was still here.

Does anyone know the location of where the registry key is stored in?

```
$RegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2"
$RegName = "Settings"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name $RegName -Value $RegValue
```

Does anyone knows what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

A PS Script to toggle taskbar top or bottom, restarts Explorer in the process.

```
$RegistryPath =  'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3'
$Name = "Settings"

$NewValue = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath
$NewValue.Settings[12] = 4-$NewValue.Settings[12]

Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $NewValue.Settings
Stop-Process -Name "Explorer"
```